# How to query datetime literals and null values in Linq predicate?

Tags: c#, linq, predicate, literals

In my current query I'm having an error like this:

```
The datetime literal value '2012-05-24' is not valid.
```

For regular linq query it seems like this:

```
_listHistory = (from item in dbase.histories
                where item.UserID == details.UserID && item.FriendID.HasValue == true && item.LogDate < today
                select item).OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDate).Take(take).Skip(skip).ToList();
```

I will be dealing with number of table "`Columns`" so I have to use linq predicate:

```
string predicate = string.Format("it.UserID=={0} && CAST(it.{1} as Edm.Int64) != null  && it.LogDate <= DATETIME'{2}'",
            details.UserID, columnname, string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", today));

_listHistory = dbase.histories.Where(predicate)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDate).Take(take).Skip(skip).ToList();
```

But this query result the error above. Can anyone help me to construct my linq query?
It is my first time to deal with Linq predicates and literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could likely use the [dynamic LINQ support](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) instead, but assuming this is Entity Query Language, it appears that you can construct the datetime with a call to CreateDateTime:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx

```
CreateDateTime( year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
```